# Change color of every second element in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, background-color

My RecyclerView is having some elements in it. Now I tried to change background color of every second element, but my code doesn't work... It is my method **onBindViewHolder**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(CityViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String cityName = cityList.get(position);
    holder.cityTextView.setText(cityName);

    if (position%2 == 0) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorLightGrey));
    }
    else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorGrey));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the result of your code? What's happening currently?

Comment: I suppose you have refference to activity in your adapter try this activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightGrey). All other in your code looks well

Comment: What's the output? Add screenshot.

Comment: It just doensn't change background-color

Comment: But output will be more helpful for us

Comment: @KonstantinVolkov I tried this: "(Activity)context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightGrey);", but I need Theme theme as a second parameter in getColor()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `setBackgroundColor` method on the root view of your `RecyclerView` single item, and not on the `itemView`. something like this:

```
holder.yourRootView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorLightGrey));
```

Don't forget to find it first, in your `ViewHolder` constructor:

```
public class CityViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private FrameLayout yourRootView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        yourRootView = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.item_root_view);
    }
}
```

You can use any view type instead of `FrameLayout` according to your item.

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this instead (same place in your adapter):

```
if (position%2 == 0) {
     holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fafafa"));
} else {
     holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
}
```